# DataGridView doesn't show scrollbar

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

DataGridView doesn't show scrollbar although all the configuration are default.
I didn't define the columns before running or use any binding, only that code down here, (datagrid creates the columns in real time when
the data arrives).
I saw the posts about the frozen cells/columns , but in my case there is no columns of cells in first place before running.

```
dAdapter4.SelectCommand = activityOnlyCmd;
var ds4 = new DataSet();

try
{
    dConn.Open();
    dAdapter4.Fill(ds4,"activities");
    dConn.Close();

    dataGridView.DataSource = ds4.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: `.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both`? You might inadvertently set the `.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None`.

Comment: @user2695221 : u r issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows

```
try
{
    dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

    dConn.Open();
    dAdapter4.Fill(ds4,"activities");
    dConn.Close();    
    dataGridView.DataSource = ds4.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

and try again

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of DataGridview

```
dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```